# regular expressions and tab delimited datafile

Tags: php, regex, database

I want to build a tab delimited datafile. I am using regular expressions to extract the required info i.e. registrant name, registrant email and domain name. I want the code outputs results for each domain lookup in tab delimited format. Can you please give me hints about how I can achieve this?

```
<?php

     require 'Net/Whois.php';
     $server = 'whois.networksolutions.com';


    $content=file('query-file.txt');

    foreach ($content as $query)

    { 


    $whois = new Net_Whois;
    $data = $whois->query($query, $server);

               if (preg_match_all('/^registrant name: (.*)/im', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER))

                    // Print the matches:
                    {
                            echo '<pre>' .  $matches[0][1] .  '</pre>';

                     } else {

                     echo 'not found!</p>';
                     }  


      if (preg_match_all('/^registrant email: (.*)/im', $data, $email, PREG_SET_ORDER))

                    // Print the matches:
                    {
                            echo '<pre>' .  $email[0][1] .  '</pre>';

                     } else {

                     echo 'not found!</p>';
                     }      

        if (preg_match_all('/^Domain Name: (.*)/im', $data, $email, PREG_SET_ORDER))

                    // Print the matches:
                    {
                            echo '<pre>' .  $email[0][1] .  '</pre>';

                     } else {

                     echo 'not found!</p>';
                     }                    


    }

?>
```

output of the code

```
Dns Admin

dns-admin@google.com

google.com

not found!

not found!

not found!

Domain Name Manager

tmgroup@turner.com

cnn.com

Domain Administrator

domains@microsoft.com

msn.com

Domain Administrator

domains@microsoft.com

hotmail.com

Domain Administrator

domainadmin@yahoo-inc.com

yahoo.com

DNS Admin

gmail-abuse@google.com

gmail.com
```

DESIRED OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE

```
Dns Admin   dns-admin@google.com   google.com
Domain Name Manager   tmgroup@turner.com    cnn.com
Domain Administrator   domains@microsoft.com   msn.com

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo` save the data to an array for each of the if statements:

```
$data[] = $matches[0][1];
```

else

```
$data[] = 'not found!';
```

Then at the end of the loop (after the last if), join the data with tabs:

```
$lines[] = implode("\t", $data) . "\n";
```

Then after the loop has finished (}) save the lines to a file:

```
file_put_contents('path/to/file.txt', $lines);
```